# jplayer ajax running multiple times with timeupdate

Tags: php, ajax, jplayer

I'm attempting to send the currentTime, duration, and currentPrecentAbsolute values out to a php page that grabs those variables and stores them into a database using ajax. I have it working fine on the pause event, however when I try using timeupdate I get multiple calls.

I want to be able to auto send the data when the currentPercentAbsolute reaches 25%, 50% and 75%. I know what the problem is, I'm just unsure how to solve it. Timeupdate speed is variable across browsers, I believe with a default of around 250ms. So while my percent is 25%, 50% and or 75%, the ajax will continue to run. Roughly 4 times (4*250ms in a second). And of course that's only if the video is roughly 100 seconds long. If it's 200 seconds long, currentPercentAbsolute would stay at those percentages a whole second longer, running my ajax 8 times.

So ultimately my question is, what's a better way to do what I'm attempting. On a side note, I'd also like to implement

```
$(window).unload(function(){my ajax call in here});
```

to be able to grab the same stats in the event the user closes the window without finishing the video. I had it working, but ran into the same problem. It runs at every iteration of timeupdate. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

My Code For timeupdate

```
timeupdate: function (event) {
    var totaltime = Math.floor(event.jPlayer.status.duration);
    var currenttime = Math.floor(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime);
    var percent = Math.floor(event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute);                  

    if(percent == '25'){
        $('#timeNow').html(currenttime);
        $('#percentNow').html(percent); 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'teststats.php',
            data : {timeWatched : currenttime, percentWatched : percent, totalTime : totaltime},
            success : function(data) { }
        });                     
    }
    if(percent == '50'){
        $('#timeNow').html(currenttime);
        $('#percentNow').html(percent);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'teststats.php',
            data : {timeWatched : currenttime, percentWatched : percent, totalTime : totaltime},
            success : function(data) { }
        });                         
    }
    if(percent == '75'){
        $('#timeNow').html(currenttime);
        $('#percentNow').html(percent);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'teststats.php',
            data : {
                timeWatched : currenttime, percentWatched : percent, totalTime : totaltime},
            success : function(data) { }
        });                         
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the multiple runs on this.
I declared 3 global variables, then did

`if((percent == '25') && (!a)){`

and set

`a = true;`

inside the if statement.

Still running into problems with

```
timeupdate: function(event) {
    var totaltime = Math.floor(event.jPlayer.status.duration);
    var currenttime = Math.floor(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime);
    var percent = Math.floor(event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute);  

    $(window).blind('beforeunload', function() {
        if(!d){
            d = true;
            $('#timeNow').html(currenttime);
            $('#percentNow').html(percent);
            $('#totalTime').html(totaltime);                            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'teststats.php',
                data : {
                    timeWatched : currenttime, 
                    percentWatched : percent, 
                    totalTime : totaltime
                },
                success : function(data) { }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And maybe it's doing what it's supposed to be doing. 
All 3 variables (currentime, percent, and totaltime) are kicking out as 0's.  I'm not sure if jplayer clears the values from timeupdate when I attempt to close the browser window or navigate to another url.  Anyone have any thoughts on this?  Thanks.